# WSFC with SQL transactional replication issue

Tags: failover, transactional-replication

On my UAT environment, I have 2 nodes, WSFC and SQL transactional replication is setup. Sometime we failover From Node A (Active) to Node B (passive), when Node B becomes active after I failover the replication will break I have to set it up using the script, or GUI. so far all databases are small BUT my question: is there a way to failover nodes without messing up replication? Thanks

Comment: Seems like this is related to the SQL Server database only.

Comment: I removed the <sql> tag, since this isn't related to ANSI/ISO SQL. Add a tag for the dbms you're using instead.